# SwiftUI: How to truncate button label in keyboard toolbar?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can I make sure the button label will truncate in the keyboard toolbar and not extend over the edges of the screen? Added the button to the `VStack` for reference (this is what I try to achive in the toolbar).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            myButton
            TextField("Enter Text", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        myButton
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    var myButton: some View {
        Button {
            // do something
        } label: {
            Text("A possibly very long text that absolutely needs to be truncated.")
                .lineLimit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you'd do this the same way you would with any other `Text` / `Label` component using the `truncationMode()` modifier:

```swift
Text("A possibly very long text that absolutely needs to be truncated.")
    .frame(maxWidth: 150) // Just an example value
    .truncationMode(.tail) // Or .center, .lead, whatever you need
```

Comment: If I set a `maxWidth` as you did, this will work, but then the label does not adapt to the available space anymore. I want the label to take as much space as possible without becoming larger than the screen. Oddly, if I just use the `Text`without the button, truncation works perfectly without the need for `.frame` or `.truncationMode`. So it seems the button is the issue here.